# In Haskell apply sqrt in list of tuples

Tags: haskell

I have made a list of tuples and I want to filter this list based on whether the square root of the second member of each tuple is an integer:

```
isInt :: (RealFrac a) => a -> Bool
test m n = filter (\(a,b) -> isInt (sqrt b)) 
             ( zip [m..n]  
                ( map (\y -> sum y ) $ 
                    map (\x -> map (^2) x) 
                        [  filter (\z -> mod j z ==0 ) [1..j] 
                           |  j <- [i | i <- [m..n]]  ] ))
isInt x  =  x == fromInteger (round x)
```

But every time, I get this error:

```
  • Ambiguous type variable ‘b0’ arising from a use of ‘print’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Show b0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘b0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance (Show b, Show a) => Show (Either a b)
          -- Defined in ‘Data.Either’
        instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        ...plus 23 others
        ...plus 43 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any `print` in your code...

Comment: Can you please explain *what* you aim to do. It looks like you make things too complex. For exaple `[i | i <- [m..n]]` is just the same as `[m..n]`. You furthermore use `Float`s and `Int`s at the same time.

Comment: @bereal: the print is probably due to the implicit `print` in ghci.

Comment: And please format your code in a sensible way. Lines with >90 chars get very hard  to read.

Comment: Ideas, yes, *see the derived type* with `GHCi> :t test`: `test :: (RealFrac a, Integral a, Floating a) => a -> a -> [(a, a)]`. an Integral, and a Floating at the same time?..

Comment: Also: `\y -> sum y == sum` and `\x -> map (^2) x == map (^2)`. Break your code up into more manageable functions; `test` doesn't have to be responsible for generating the list of tuples it is testing. And finally, `map f (map g someList)` is the same as `map (f . g) someList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do *not* check if a value is square by calculating the square root. This maps items to the "floating point world". This can have rounding errors, etc. It furthermore makes the code harder to read, since you need to do all those conversions between the integer world and the floating point world.

You can for example use the [**`isSquare :: Integral a => a -> Bool`** function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.9.0.0/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Powers-Squares.html#v:isSquare) from the [**`arithmoi`** package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi).

```
import Math.NumberTheory.Powers.Squares(isSquare)

test :: Integral i => i -> i -> [(i,i)]
test m n = filter (isSquare . snd)
    [ (j, (sum . map (^2) . filter ((==) 0 . mod j)) [1..j]) | j <- [m..n]]
```

For example:

```
Prelude Math.NumberTheory.Powers.Squares> test 0 1000
[(0,0),(1,1),(42,2500),(246,84100),(287,84100),(728,722500)]
```